# Pass clipboard contents into a new file name

Tags: excel, vba

Moving file with following code:

```
Name Range("E1") & Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value As Range("C2") & Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
```

Where: E1 = path to current folder; H = file name; C2 = path to a new folder.

Want to pass clipboard contents into new file name:
1) adding clipboard contents as first set of characters before the original file name should be easy, something like:
`... As Range("C2") & clipb & Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value`, I just need to assign contents of clipboard to "clipb";
2) it gets more interesting if original file name looks something like this "First Second Third" and I want to pass clipboard content into new file name like so  "First clipb Second Third" or "First Second clipb Third"

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/clipboard.aspx